# how to filter primeng template field

Tags: angular, primeng

here is my code

```
  <p-dataTable [value]="postData" [globalFilter]="gb" [rows]="5" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]">
    <p-column field="state" header="state" ></p-column>
    <p-column styleClass="col-button" field="Activity_Dep" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <span>test</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template let-rowdata="rowData" pTemplate="body">
      <p>{{rowdata.Activity_Dep + rowdata.Activity_Group}}</p>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

The globalFilter works with p-column 1 , but when not work with ng-template

how can i filter with ng-template?

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden columns with parsed data and set **filterField** column property to that column so when you search it will search on that column instead of the visible one.